# How do I get the picture size with PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, image

How do I get a size of a pictures sides with PIL or any other Python library?

Comment: See also: [image size in bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11904141/562769)

Answer (score 787, accepted):

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('whatever.png')
width, height = im.size
```

According to the [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111195341/http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm).

Comment: If you also want to know the number of channels, you should use ```im.mode```.  Since PIL is a bit cryptic, you can also use numpy: ```numpy.array(im).shape```

Comment: Note @AlexKreimer that using `.shape` results in different returns since height is the first of the 2d array, then width. Therefore `height, width = np.array(im).shape`

Comment: Please use `with`.

Comment: @AlexKreimer : `np.array(im).shape` does NOT return number of channels, it rather returns `height` and `width`!

Comment: @FäridAlijani sure, it returns the shape of a tensor, which (possibly) includes the number of channels.  If you only get 2 dims it probably means that the number of channels is 1.

Comment: I am afraid it is not true though, cuz I tried this on RGB image with 3 channels!

Comment: It may be worth noting that `Image.open()` reads the metadata without loading the full image, which may have pros (faster) or cons (duplication) depending on your use case. Use `Image.load()` to read the full image. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19034942/1295595

Answer (score 112):

You can use Pillow ([Website](http://python-pillow.org/), [Documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/), [GitHub](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow), [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/)). Pillow has the same interface as PIL, but works with Python 3.

### Installation

```
$ pip install Pillow
```

If you don't have administrator rights (sudo on Debian), you can use

```
$ pip install --user Pillow
```

Other notes regarding the installation are [here](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/installation.html#simple-installation).

### Code

```
from PIL import Image
with Image.open(filepath) as img:
    width, height = img.size
```

### Speed

This needed 3.21 seconds for 30336 images (JPGs from 31x21 to 424x428, training data from [National Data Science Bowl](http://www.kaggle.com/c/datasciencebowl) on Kaggle)

This is probably the most important reason to use Pillow instead of something self-written. And you should use Pillow instead of PIL (python-imaging), because it works with Python 3.

### Alternative #1: Numpy (deprecated)

I keep [`scipy.ndimage.imread`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.1.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.imread.html) as the information is still out there, but keep in mind:

> imread is deprecated! imread is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and [was] removed in 1.2.0.

```
import scipy.ndimage
height, width, channels = scipy.ndimage.imread(filepath).shape
```

### Alternative #2: Pygame

```
import pygame
img = pygame.image.load(filepath)
width = img.get_width()
height = img.get_height()
```

Comment: is `Image.open(filepath)` faster than `cv2.imread(filepath)` method?

Comment: `cv2.imread` appears to be faster based on https://www.kaggle.com/code/yukia18/opencv-vs-pil-speed-comparisons-for-pytorch-user

Answer (score 9):

Since `scipy`'s `imread` is deprecated, use `imageio.imread`.

1. Install - `pip install imageio`
2. Use `height, width, channels = imageio.imread(filepath).shape`

Comment: `imageio` is based on Pillow and provides a common API for different file formats. So performance should be similar to that of Pillow.

Answer (score 4):

This is a complete example loading image from URL, creating with PIL, printing the size and resizing...

```
import requests
h = { 'User-Agent': 'Neo'}
r = requests.get("https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/85c/football-1442407.jpg", headers=h)

from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
# create image from binary content
i = Image.open(BytesIO(r.content))


width, height = i.size
print(width, height)
i = i.resize((100,100))
display(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that PIL will not apply the EXIF rotation information (at least up to v7.1.1; used in many jpgs). A quick fix to accomodate this:

```
def get_image_dims(file_path):
    from PIL import Image as pilim
    im = pilim.open(file_path)
    # returns (w,h) after rotation-correction
    return im.size if im._getexif().get(274,0) < 5 else im.size[::-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you get the image size from the given URL in Python 3:

```
from PIL import Image
import urllib.request
from io import BytesIO

file = BytesIO(urllib.request.urlopen('http://getwallpapers.com/wallpaper/full/b/8/d/32803.jpg').read())
im = Image.open(file)
width, height = im.size
```

Answer (score 0):

Followings gives dimensions as well as channels:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

with Image.open(filepath) as img:
    shape = np.array(img).shape
```