# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable while reading image size

Tags: python, python-2.7

### Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import sys
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')


# Read image with opencv
img = cv2.imread("T.jpg")

print img.size
width , height = img.size
```

### Error

```
   (C:\Users\SACHIN\Anaconda2) D:\>python R6extractor.py
    6220800
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "R6extractor.py", line 14, in <module>
        width , height = img.size
    TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

But when I googled how to get the width and height of the image .Almost every example showed using width,height = image.size .And I went with it .But I am getting this error so I checked the content of image.size and I am getting  6220800.So what am I doing wrong here

Comment: Size isn't returning dimensions - you can't unpack an integer with tuple unpacking. Check the method in PIL docs.

Comment: http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm but this and this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444548/how-do-i-get-the-picture-size-with-pil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @theWanderer4865 said in the comments, `img.size` returns an integer, and you can't unpack it.

What you need to do is:

```
height, width, channels = img.shape
```

**EDIT**

If you wanted to open it using the `Image` library, the code would be like this:

```
from PIL import Image

# Read image with Image
img = Image('T.jpg')
img = cv2.imread("T.jpg")

width, height = img.size
```

Comment: I will accept this as answer but can you clarify how this works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444548/how-do-i-get-the-picture-size-with-pil

Comment: In that question, and in the documentation, they open the image through the `Image.open` method. In your code, you're using `cv2.imread` instead.

Comment: so if I use open I can actually use image.size ?

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: In short: CV2 returns img.size as integer. PIL returns img.size as (w, h)