# Can python-docx add a picture that is a link to an external image file?

Tags: python, image, ms-word, docx, python-docx

I am using the python-docx library ( https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/ ) to write a Word document.

## Embed a picture

I can add a picture that is embedded in the document, using the API of the python-docx library.  For example:

```
from docx import Document

doc = Document()
par = doc.add_paragraph( 'Embed picture:' )
run = par.add_run()
run.add_picture( 'puppy.png' )
doc.save( 'test.docx' )
```

The picture becomes an ImagePart that is stored within the document:

```
word/
  media/
    image1.png
```

And the Relationship that points to that Image part is:

```
<Relationships ...>
  ...
  <Relationship Id="rId4" Type=".../image" Target="media/image1.png"/>
```

## Link a picture

I would prefer to add a picture that links to an external image file.  This is something that you can do within Microsoft Word.  The python-docx library does not have a convenient API for that.  However, some of the underlying code seems to have support for linking to an external file

Therefore, I started my own utility function to link a picture to an external file.  For example:

```
from docx import Document

doc = Document()
par = doc.add_paragraph( 'Link picture:' )
run = par.add_run()
Util.Run_add_picture( run, 'puppy.png', is_external = True )
doc.save( 'test.docx' )
```

Which would lead to the Relationship for the picture being something like the following:

```
<Relationships ...>
  ...
  <Relationship Id="rId4" Type=".../image" Target="file:///C:\work\puppy.png" TargetMode="External"/>
```

I was encouraged that some of the underlying code seems to have support for linking to an external file.  For example, `docx.opc.part.Part.relate_to()` has an `is_external` parameter that defaults to false.  It seemed reasonable to invent my own utility wrappers for `Run.add_picture()`, and the functions that calls, so that I could pass along an `is_external` parameter with a value of true.

For another example, `docx.oxml.shape.CT_Blip` has `embed` and `link` properties, and if you assign the relationship ID to the latter instead of the former, that should percolate into other places and generate the desired markup in the document.  It seemed reasonable to invent a utility wrapper for `docx.oxml.shape.CT_Picture.new()`, and the functions that call it, so that I could pass along an `is_external` parameter with a value of true, and then do something like the following:

```
@staticmethod
def CT_Picture_new( pic_id, filename, relationship_id, cx, cy, is_external ):
  pic = parse_xml( CT_Picture._pic_xml() )
  pic.nvPicPr.cNvPr.id = pic_id
  pic.nvPicPr.cNvPr.name = filename

  # The important change that pays attention to given is_external parameter.
  if is_external:
    pic.blipFill.blip.link = relationship_id
  else:
    pic.blipFill.blip.embed = relationship_id

  pic.spPr.cx = cx
  pic.spPr.cy = cy
  return pic
```

So far, I have utility functions that take the place of, and provide a way to specify an `is_external` parameter, for:

- `docx.text.run.Run.add_picture()`
- `docx.parts.story.BaseStoryPart.new_pic_inline()`
- `docx.parts.story.BaseStoryPart.get_or_add_image()`
- `docx.oxml.shape.CT_Inline.new_pic_inline()`
- `docx.oxml.shape.CT_Picture.new()`

## Too many rabbit holes

Alas, I still get an exception when I save the document.

> TypeError: Argument must be bytes or unicode, got 'ImagePart'

I think the next thing that I must change is how a `Relationship` object is populated;  the `target_ref` property needs to be assigned just a sting path to the external image file, not an `ImagePart` object.

I must give up for awhile.  Are there any plans to support linking a picture to an external image file?   Or, a simpler workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This is how i solved it with comments inside

```py
from docx.opc.constants import RELATIONSHIP_TYPE
from docx.oxml import CT_Inline, parse_xml, CT_Picture
from docx.shape import InlineShape
from docx.shared import Length
from docx.text.run import Run


def add_linked_pic(r: Run, image_path: str, width: Length, height: Length) -> InlineShape:
    """
    Image will be inserted as character without embedding, just as link.
    :param r: run
    :param image_path:
        Seems like it has to be absolute path.as_uri() like "file:///full/path/file.jpg".
        It seems that it also works with relative path like "./folder/image.jpg"
    :param width: size of image in document
    :param height: size of image in document
    :return:
    """

    # create RELATION.
    relations = r.part.rels
    rel_id = relations._next_rId
    relations.add_relationship(reltype=RELATIONSHIP_TYPE.IMAGE, target=image_path, rId=rel_id, is_external=True)

    # Comment about pic_id from python-docx creators:
    # -- Word doesn't seem to use this, but does not omit it
    pic_id = 0

    # Next code taken from this method:
    # def new(cls, pic_id, filename, rId, cx, cy):
    # Just one line changed in order to replace `r:embed` with `r:link`.

    # The following lines were created to make variable names same as in python-docx method.
    filename = image_path  # Filename - something useless. will make it equal to image_path
    cx = width
    cy = height

    # Expand that code as CT_Picture.new(pic_id, filename, rId, cx, cy):
    pic = parse_xml(CT_Picture._pic_xml())
    pic.nvPicPr.cNvPr.id = pic_id
    pic.nvPicPr.cNvPr.name = filename

    # pic.blipFill.blip.embed = rId  # This line is replaced with next one
    pic.blipFill.blip.link = rel_id

    pic.spPr.cx = cx
    pic.spPr.cy = cy

    shape_id = r.part.next_id

    # Now from here: inline = cls.new(cx, cy, shape_id, pic)
    inline = CT_Inline.new(cx, cy, shape_id, pic)
    r._r.add_drawing(inline)

    # For embedding image there is get_or_add_image_part method.
    # We don't need it here.

    return InlineShape(inline)
```

Comment: Is it possible to scale the picture automatically such way that you provide ex. width and the height sets automatically (like in add_picture method)?

Comment: @Adam I would [use PIL in order to get geometry of an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444548/how-do-i-get-the-picture-size-with-pil). Then it is easy to calculate length of a side knowing the other one.